# Android widgets

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-widget

How to add imges from SD card in to image widget which is displaying some images in android?

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to include an ImageView component on your widget than using one of the RemoteView function setImageViewUri(viewId, uri) you can load the image.

You will need to pass the ImageView ID and create an Uri pointing to the SDCARD.

> Uri.fromFile(new
>   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"file
>   name"))"

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() - path to SDcard or any other external storage